# How to find the most common name in 2 related lists

Tags: python, list, collections, counter

I would like to seek help from the community.. I have 2 related lists here:

```
names = ['alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady']
votes = [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True]
```

The `votes` list is a result of a facial recognition algorithm matching from the corresponding `names` list. Then I shall link each `True` vote to the corresponding name, and find the most frequently occurred name to be the final 'winner'.

I have tried 2 ways:

```
characters = {}
for name, vote in list(zip(names, votes)):
    if vote == True:
        characters[name] = characters.get(name, 0) + 1
#print(characters)
print(max(characters, key=characters.get))
```

The output is 'owen_grady'

```
from collections import Counter

characters = [name for name, vote in list(zip(names, votes)) if vote == True]
#print(characters)
print(Counter(characters).most_common()[0][0])
```

The output is also 'owen_grady'. Which way is more efficient: Dictionary? or List Comprehension with Counter?

My ultimate question: is there another way (the **most efficient**) to get the result? I would like the output to be just 'owen_grady'

Comment: You can just apply [`itertools.compress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress): `Counter(compress(names, votes))`. And minor improvement as you need just most common, pass `1` to you [`.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) call so it will return just single pair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.compress()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) to filter all *false* entries. Option with `Counter` should be most efficient, just use *`n`* argument in [`.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) to let it return a single pair.

Code:

```py
from itertools import compress
from collections import Counter

names = ['alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady']
votes = [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True]

most_common = Counter(compress(names, votes)).most_common(1)[0][0]
# Or with some syntax sugar:
# [(most_common, _)] = Counter(compress(names, votes)).most_common(1)
```

---

**Upd.** I've made [some benchmarks](https://tio.run/##1ZZJj5swFIDv/Aorl4AGRZPlUFXiVKm/oLcoslxwEk@9ION0mlT97akXCEtCBoeoUjmAbL/le/Z7z@RHtRd8@SmX5/NWCgZSQSlOFRG8AITlQiqQ4S06UJWRVMXgizhwhWVghUWOJVJCVpJEYbbD6rKux1IJQS@mUsFyiYsiCAKOGC5AAtZTRBGHO4m4msbg4VFKEZEYZhhJwnfPnMGUEgwLpBTF8lkTRLMzRPV2s7HDN7HncI8YEzx7xli8Y7uv2fHh0Sb4KZQ73m/ygGPwFdHiP/o46O57EwS6FsCWyEKFKAbfo88B0E@6RxKlOtdNwL//2LmtrgqT4jEwOwEIB5RorRPJnWapah6ydTJJYr3UC23ba2Nuoz3UUzNdbKHz8hqBFzC3qhKrg@SAoV9hLRqDH/iYtFWjRjxQ5IowcsJZb2SNPhASrrVvx3kJ8SrCDyJ7Se4FMDPNpQgjF0jdacJ5FK1fm0cD34naw6rVwPljAZlQKhvdeP4V@qIX3SZTGy/yOPzUdPGo3/FylONCZ2WtFHl7X43yrm@eE@Y@DAVOdevrdWrP@OOC7tbxpglWXptNpBkTOnIdjO67ocmDSyo4ngEVGfaQXaAqpsiHZX4LpnVCTaCu0fbh9BjWWBAaZgjNdk2hvs8Ih3DqbJZ/Czp8TJSdyfVlrMKJa73RJC7XZu5TLdh/CrcNhRHSSXDIk4n9F6lcVMatRgyaKpMymZrOGqfQ57Yh4g1Q6w5A6fa1XqCuoD9Wx4I33GIo3GI03MIbbjkUbjkabukNtxoKtxoNt7oLV3bFGzTlio97pzLA3/16u5LxZxhYcTfbXj9RW@4BqpaBa7Lz@S8) and it seems like for this particular case slightly optimized first method demonstrates better performance:

```py
from itertools import compress

names = ['alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady']
votes = [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True]

characters = list(compress(names, votes))
most_common = max(set(characters), key=characters.count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to stay with the `Counter` module solution in addition to the `zip()` function:

```
names = ['alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'alan_grant', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'claire_dearing', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ellie_sattler', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'ian_malcolm', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'john_hammond', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady', 'owen_grady']
votes = [True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, True, True, True, True]

from collections import Counter
import itertools

r = Counter(zip(names, votes))
for i in list(r.keys()):
    if i[1] == False:
        del r[i]
print(r)
```

**Output:**

```
Counter({('owen_grady', True): 4, ('alan_grant', True): 1})
```

Comment: Author need to filter `False` values and not count them at all.

Comment: I would like the output to be 'owen_grady'

Comment: @perpetual-student I have added a dictionary traversal to apply your condition. Also, you can check the maximum dict value to get the most common element